# JS code on clicking button inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView control,inside of which I am having a file upload control with a button to upload files, Each FileControl have its own upload button, I am uploading files using RowCommand Event.Now I have to show progress bar of file upload control which I have implemented like in this link's 3rd answer [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1889554.aspx?How%20set%20progress%20bar%20on%20file%20upload%20) with some modification in JS

The problem I am facing is that if I click on 2nd Row's upload button of GridView,Its validating only Row's Control.

This is my Grid View

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="Grid1_RowDataBound"
                                    OnRowCommand="Grid1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="Grid1_RowDeleting"
                                    CssClass="table">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Files" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridViewHeader">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                             <asp:FileUpload ID="File1" runat="server" Width="98%" CssClass="filestat" />
                                               <asp:Button ID="btnuploadfiles" runat="server" CommandName="upload" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="return ProgressBar('File1')" />
                                             </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                         </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

and my JS code

```
function ProgressBar(Id) {
            var fileControl = GetClientID(Id).attr("id");
            if (document.getElementById(fileControl).value != "") {
                $("#divUpload").fadeIn("slow");
                $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
                document.getElementById("divUpload").style.height = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
                id = setInterval("progress()", 20);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Select a file to upload");
                return false;
            }

        }
//This function returns me ClientID of the server control       
        function GetClientID(id, context) {
            var el = $("#" + id, context);
            if (el.length < 1)
                el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
            return el;
        }
```

I also have tried setting OnClientClick from RowDataBound,but its still validating only first Row.

```
                               protected void Grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
    var btnupd = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnuploadfiles");

        btnupd.OnClientClick = "return ProgressBar('File1')";
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the context by default, if you don't specify it? Have you checked that GetClientID returns the correct element (row), or always the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following;

```
$("#<%=Grid1.ClientID%> tr").click(function(){
   alert("Row clicked");
});
```

I think using the ClientID function would be more suitable and clear for you. Getting the tr clicked, you should be able to read the cells in the actual array of tds then.

Try adding this

```
protected void Grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var button = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnuploadfiles");
        var fileUpload = (FileUpload)e.Row.FindControl("File1");

        string className = "class_" + new Random().Next();

        button.Attributes.Add("class", "rowClick");
        fileUpload.Attributes.Add("class", "rowClick"); 

        button.Attributes.Add("customClass", className);
        button.Attributes.Add("customClass", className); 
    }
}
```

And for script add this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".rowClick").click(function () {
          var customClass = this.attr("customClass"); 
          alert("Now the current row you selected has this as a common class : " + customClass);
      });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,how will I get that btnupload is clicked in this code?

Comment: Edited my answer. I have added a custom class for each FileUpload and button in each row. So now you would know which row you have selected, and what FileUpload you want to access depending on your current row.